# Not able to deploy contract on bsc network using truffle

Tags: ethereum, truffle, binance, bsc

same code I have deployed on bsctest network and ropsten but unable to deploy on bscmain network

ERROR : Unhandled error. ({ code: -32000, message: 'header not found' })

privatetest@testcms:~/signcontract$ truffle migrate --reset --network bsc

## Compiling your contracts...

Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

## Starting migrations...

> Network name:    'bsc'
> Network id:      56
> Block gas limit: 100000000 (0x5f5e100)

## 1_initial_migration.js

### Deploying 'Migrations'

> transaction hash:    0xfe684e89b8c275483263248a818533432bda9d4f308ef4f09ee8fda2d783ff3e
> ⠇ Blocks: 17           Seconds: 68Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({ code: -32000, message: 'header not found' })
> at Web3ProviderEngine.emit (events.js:304:17)
> at /home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:57:14
> at afterRequest (/home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:151:21)
> at /home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:176:21
> at /home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:238:9
> at /home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16
> at replenish (/home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:61:25)
> at /home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/async/internal/eachOfLimit.js:71:9
> at eachLimit (/home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/async/eachLimit.js:43:36)
> at /home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/async/internal/doLimit.js:9:16
> at end (/home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/index.js:217:5)
> at Request._callback (/home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/@trufflesuite/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:70:28)
> at Request.self.callback (/home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
> at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Request. (/home/privatetest/signcontract/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
> at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)